# Ajuda com placeholder que não muda de cor

Tags: css, input, algoritmo-de-busca, firefox, placeholder

Pessoal eu preciso muito da ajuda de vocês.

Eu tô desenvolvendo um site. Tõ estudando mais precisamente html5 e css3 e tô com baita de um problema que não consigo resolver...

Aqui o formato do site no CodePen: https://codepen.io/sandsoncosta/pen/XRLvvW

E caso queiram baixar no computador pra ver, Google Drive, eu acho que seria muito bom que baixassem, porque até no codepen não ta da forma certa: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B28SaVWuwZ5kSlZURWlWRlljdjg/view

Meu problema é o seguinte:

Eu não consigo fazer o placeholder ficar branco no firefox:
O site abaixo, mas ta no codepen e pra download... Como vocês podem ver abaixo o placeholder está cinza, mas se baixarem o arquivo e executarem no google chrome, no internet explorer, no microsoft edge, o placeholder vai funcionar certinho...

Já no firefox ele não fica branco... Se eu colocar por exemplo, azul, ele fica azul, mas fico meio transparente... Já nos outros navegadores, ele fica azul normal, bem forte, bem vivo.

Alguém poderia me ajudar nisso?

```css
/*@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');*/
@font-face {
 font-family: "Chicle-Regular";
 src: url(../fonts/Chicle-Regular.ttf);
 font-size: 1em;
}

header {
 width: 100%;
 height: 150px;
 background-color: rgba(94, 41, 146, 0.9);
 z-index: 2;
 position: relative;
 
}
header .container {
 position: relative;
}
header .header-black {
 background-color: #000;
 height: 40px;
 
}
header .header-black li {
 background-image: url(https://image.prntscr.com/image/7924bdab73cc417cbcee7f8f104f8c55.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 4px;
}
header .header-black li.clube01 {
 background-position: 0 0;
}
header .header-black li.clube02 {
 background-position: -48px 0;
}
header .header-black li.clube03 {
 background-position: -96px 0;
}
header .header-black li.clube04 {
 background-position: -140px 0;
}
header .header-black li.clube05 {
 background-position: -192px 0;
}
header .header-black li.clube06 {
 background-position: -240px 0;
}
header .header-black li.clube07 {
 background-position: -288px 0;
}
header .header-black li.clube08 {
 background-position: -336px 0;
}
header .header-black li.clube09 {
 background-position: -381px 0;
}
header .header-black li.clube10 {
 background-position: -429px 0;
}
header .header-black li.clube11 {
 background-position: -480px 0;
}
header .header-black li.clube12 {
 background-position: -528px 0;
}
header .header-black li.clube13 {
 background-position: -576px 0;
}
header .header-black li.clube14 {
 background-position: -627px 0;
}
header .header-black li.clube15 {
 background-position: -672px 0;
}
header .header-black li.clube16 {
 background-position: -720px 0;
}
header .header-black li.clube17 {
 background-position: -764px 0;
}
header .header-black li.clube18 {
 background-position: -807px 0;
}
header .header-black li.clube19 {
 background-position: -856px 0;
}
header .header-black li.clube20 {
 background-position: -903px 0;
}
header .header-black li.clube21 {
 background-position: -948px 0;
}
header .header-black li.clube22 {
 background-position: -994px 0;
}
header .header-black li a {
 width: 32px;
 height: 32px;
 display: block;
}
header #logo {
 position: absolute;
 top: 20px;
}
#menu {
 margin: 12px 0;
}
#menu li {
 display: inline-block;
 font-family: "Chicle-Regular";
}
#menu li.search {
 width: 182px;
}
#menu li.search input {
 background-color: #5c2d90;
 color: #fff;
 border: none;
 height: 30px;
 line-height: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
}
*ESSA PARTE É PARA MUDAR A COR*/

/* PARA CHROME, SAFARI, ANDROID E IOS */
#menu li.search ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 color: #fff;
}
/*PARA INTERNET EXPLORER */
#menu li.search :-ms-input-placeholder {
 color: #fff;
}
/*PARA MICROSOF EDGE */
#menu li.search ::-ms-input-placeholder {
 color: #fff;
}
/*PARA FIREFOX 18- */
#menu li.search input:-moz-placeholder {
 color: #fff;
}
/*PARA FIREFOX 19+ */
#menu li.search input::-moz-placeholder {
 color: #fff;
}
/*  PARA OPERA */
#menu li.search ::-o-input-placeholder {
 color: #fff;
}
#menu li.search button {
 background: none;
 border: none;
 position: absolute;
 right: 3px;
 top: 7px;

}
#menu li.search button i { 
 font-size: 14px;
 color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}
#menu li a {
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 16px;
 padding: 16px 25px;
}
#menu li.search .input-group {
 top: 8px;
}
#banner {
 width: 100%;
 height: 728px;
 position: relative;
 background: url(https://image.prntscr.com/image/45b6cf6518934924bba52db479c19c1b.jpg) no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 top: -110px;
 background-position: 0 -110px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


</head>

<body>

<header>

 <div class="container"> 
  <img id="logo" src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/d7dbe9661b2447a2abe06197f64640e1.png" alt="logo">
 </div>

<div class="header-black">
 <div class="container">
<ul class="pull-right">
 <li class="clube01"><a href="#"></a></li>
 <li class="clube02"><a href="#"></a></li>
 <li class="clube03"><a href="#"></a></li>
 <li class="clube04"><a href="#"></a></li>
 <li class="clube05"><a href="#"></a></li>
 <li class="clube06"><a href="#"></a></li>
 <li class="clube07"><a href="#"></a></li>
 <li class="clube08"><a href="#"></a></li>
 <li class="clube09"><a href="#"></a></li>
 <li class="clube10"><a href="#"></a></li>
 <li class="clube11"><a href="#"></a></li>
 <li class="clube12"><a href="#"></a></li>
 <li class="clube13"><a href="#"></a></li>
 <li class="clube14"><a href="#"></a></li>
 <li class="clube15"><a href="#"></a></li>
 <li class="clube16"><a href="#"></a></li>
 <li class="clube17"><a href="#"></a></li>
 <li class="clube18"><a href="#"></a></li>
 <li class="clube19"><a href="#"></a></li>
 <li class="clube20"><a href="#"></a></li>
 <li class="clube21"><a href="#"></a></li>
 <li class="clube22"><a href="#"></a></li>
</ul>
 </div>
</div>
 
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <nav id="menu" class="pull-right">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Tickets</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Schedule</a></li>
    <li class="search">
     <div class="input-group">
      <input type="search" placeholder="Procurar...">
       <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </button>
       </span>
     </div>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </div>
</div>

</header>

<section>
 <div id="banner">Estou bem aqui hahahaha</div>
</section>

<script src="1.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

é preciso mudar o opacity. E falta também o caso geral sem prefixos.

```
#menu li.search::input-placeholder {
  color: #fff;
}

#menu li.search input::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Opa! Deu certo, Tomás! Vlw!